# Remaining days showing NaN in Firefox, Chrome works perfect - Stack Overflow

Tags: asp.net

Date Calculation Remaining Days shows NaN Firefox only.but work fine in chrome

```
function check() {
        debugger
        $("#txtscap1_domicilesensitivecountryfromdate").on("click", function () {
        debugger
        var today = new Date();
        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        ];
        var d = today.getFullYear() + "-" + monthNames[today.getMonth()] + "-" + today.getDate();
        var date = $("#txtscap1_domicilesensitivecountryfromdate").val();

        var date1 = Date.parse(d);
        var date2 = Date.parse(date);

        var days = Math.ceil((date1 - date2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        $("#txtscap1_domicilesensitivecountry_trigger").val(days);
        // alert(days);
        });
    }
```

2.5

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle where we can reproduce your issue?